# How to disable the Submit button on a the delete page form?

Tags: 7, forms

I made a form_alter and trying to disable the submit button by greying it out by using the #disabled option on the form api. I know i can just do a unset() on the submit button, but was wondering how to use the #disabled. I tried the following:

**$form['actions']['submit']['#disabled'] = TRUE;**

But that doesn't do anything it seems. Here' my krumo output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are understanding the behavior of the '#disabled' key correctly. I tried the code you describe and it "just worked."

```
function custom_form_node_delete_confirm_alter(&$form, $form_state) {

  dsm($form['actions']['submit']);
  $form['actions']['submit']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  dsm($form['actions']['submit']);
}
```

[image: Screenshot of debug output from form alter]

My guess as to why the alteration is not creating the desired end result is that your function signature is not using the "&" with the $form variable. That character is needed for the $form variable to be "passed by reference" which allows for the changes to the variable to stick outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

By referring [Drupal 7 disable submit button](https://mcaleaa.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/drupal-7-disable-submit-button/) your code is correct. Plz refer [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1019938) or just try  [Hide submit button](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit) module..

Comment: i wanted to grey it out so you cannot click it. i thought tats built into drupal? what does #disable do then? is it the same as unset()?

Comment: i referred [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#actions),